# Samsung disable packages

Tags: android, service, samsung-mobile, android-package-managers, samsung-knox

I'm trying to create a kiosk mode application for my company and I need to disable some default packages to avoid the users to reach it.
I've using Samsung Knox which looks to be working well when this code is not executed.

The list is huge:

```
// Common packages
packages.add("android.googleSearch.googleSearchWidget");
packages.add("com.LocalFota");
packages.add("com.android.MtpApplication");
packages.add("com.android.backupconfirm");
packages.add("com.android.bluetooth");
packages.add("com.android.browser.provider");
packages.add("com.android.calendar");
packages.add("com.android.certinstaller");
packages.add("com.android.chrome");
packages.add("com.android.dreams.basic");
packages.add("com.android.dreams.phototable");
packages.add("com.android.email");
packages.add("com.android.exchange");
packages.add("com.android.facelock");
packages.add("com.android.htmlviewer");
packages.add("com.android.inputdevices");
packages.add("com.android.keychain");
packages.add("com.android.location.fused");
packages.add("com.android.mms");
packages.add("com.android.musicfx");
packages.add("com.android.nfc");
packages.add("com.android.noisefield");
packages.add("com.android.phasebeam");
packages.add("com.android.sharedstoragebackup");
packages.add("com.android.stk");
packages.add("com.android.vending");
packages.add("com.android.vpndialogs");
packages.add("com.android.wallpaper.livepicker");
packages.add("com.google.android.apps.books");
packages.add("com.google.android.apps.magazines");
packages.add("com.google.android.apps.plus");
packages.add("com.google.android.apps.uploader");
packages.add("com.google.android.backup");
packages.add("com.google.android.configupdater");
packages.add("com.google.android.feedback");
packages.add("com.google.android.gm");
packages.add("com.google.android.gms");
packages.add("com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox");
packages.add("com.google.android.marvin.talkback");
packages.add("com.google.android.music");
packages.add("com.google.android.partnersetup");
packages.add("com.google.android.play.games");
packages.add("com.google.android.setupwizard");
packages.add("com.google.android.street");
packages.add("com.google.android.syncadapters.calendar");
packages.add("com.google.android.syncadapters.contacts");
packages.add("com.google.android.talk");
packages.add("com.google.android.tts");
packages.add("com.google.android.videos");
packages.add("com.google.android.voicesearch");
packages.add("com.google.android.youtube");
packages.add("com.infraware.polarisviewer5");
packages.add("com.lifevibes.trimapp");
packages.add("com.monotype.android.font.chococooky");
packages.add("com.monotype.android.font.cooljazz");
packages.add("com.monotype.android.font.droidserifitalic");
packages.add("com.monotype.android.font.rosemary");
packages.add("com.monotype.android.font.samsungsans");
packages.add("com.qualcomm.privinit");
packages.add("com.qualcomm.timeservice");
packages.add("com.samsung.android.app.assistantmenu");
packages.add("com.samsung.android.app.colorblind");
packages.add("com.samsung.android.app.shareaccessibilitysettings");
packages.add("com.samsung.android.service.travel");
packages.add("com.samsung.android.tripwidget");
packages.add("com.samsung.android.widgetapp.briefing4x2");
packages.add("com.samsung.app.playreadyui");
packages.add("com.samsung.everglades.video");
packages.add("com.samsung.helphub");
packages.add("com.samsung.klmsagent");
packages.add("com.samsung.scrc.idi.server");
packages.add("com.samsung.shareshot");
packages.add("com.sec.android.Kies");
packages.add("com.sec.android.allshare.service.controlshare");
packages.add("com.sec.android.allshare.service.fileshare");
packages.add("com.sec.android.allshare.service.mediashare");
packages.add("com.sec.android.app.FileShareClient");
packages.add("com.sec.android.app.FileShareServer");
packages.add("com.sec.android.app.SecSetupWizard");
packages.add("com.sec.android.app.bluetoothtest");
packages.add("com.sec.android.app.camera");
packages.add("com.sec.android.app.clockpackage");
packages.add("com.sec.android.app.controlpanel");
packages.add("com.sec.android.app.easylauncher");
packages.add("com.sec.android.app.factorykeystring");
packages.add("com.sec.android.app.fm");
packages.add("com.sec.android.app.hwmoduletest");
packages.add("com.sec.android.app.keyguard");
packages.add("com.sec.android.app.keyguardbackuprestore");
packages.add("com.sec.android.app.kieswifi");
packages.add("com.sec.android.app.launcher");
packages.add("com.sec.android.app.mt");
packages.add("com.sec.android.app.music");
packages.add("com.sec.android.app.myfiles");
packages.add("com.sec.android.app.nfctest");
packages.add("com.sec.android.app.parser");
packages.add("com.sec.android.app.personalization");
packages.add("com.sec.android.app.popupcalculator");
packages.add("com.sec.android.app.popupuireceiver");
packages.add("com.sec.android.app.ringtoneBR");
packages.add("com.sec.android.app.safetyassurance");
packages.add("com.sec.android.app.samsungapps");
packages.add("com.sec.android.app.samsungapps.una2");
packages.add("com.sec.android.app.sbrowser");
packages.add("com.sec.android.app.sbrowsertry");
packages.add("com.sec.android.app.sns3");
packages.add("com.sec.android.app.sysscope");
packages.add("com.sec.android.app.translator");
packages.add("com.sec.android.app.videoplayer");
packages.add("com.sec.android.app.voicerecorder");
packages.add("com.sec.android.app.wallpaperchooser");
packages.add("com.sec.android.band");
packages.add("com.sec.android.cloudagent");
packages.add("com.sec.android.daemonapp");
packages.add("com.sec.android.directconnect");
packages.add("com.sec.android.directshare");
packages.add("com.sec.android.drmpopup");
packages.add("com.sec.android.easysettings");
packages.add("com.sec.android.fotaclient");
packages.add("com.sec.android.gallery3d");
packages.add("com.sec.android.mmapp");
packages.add("com.sec.android.preloadinstaller");
packages.add("com.sec.android.sCloudBackupApp");
packages.add("com.sec.android.sCloudBackupProvider");
packages.add("com.sec.android.sCloudRelayData");
packages.add("com.sec.android.sCloudSync");
packages.add("com.sec.android.sCloudSyncCalendar");
packages.add("com.sec.android.sCloudSyncContacts");
packages.add("com.sec.android.sCloudSyncSBrowserBookMark");
packages.add("com.sec.android.sCloudSyncSBrowserTabs");
packages.add("com.sec.android.sCloudSyncSNote");
packages.add("com.sec.android.saslideshow");
packages.add("com.sec.android.scloud.quota");
packages.add("com.sec.android.service.cm");
packages.add("com.sec.android.service.health.sensor");
packages.add("com.sec.android.widgetapp.SPlannerAppWidget");
packages.add("com.sec.android.widgetapp.alarmwidget");
packages.add("com.sec.android.widgetapp.ap.hero.accuweather");
packages.add("com.sec.android.widgetapp.ap.yahoonews");
packages.add("com.sec.android.widgetapp.ap.yahoostock.stockclock");
packages.add("com.sec.android.widgetapp.digitalclock");
packages.add("com.sec.android.widgetapp.dualclockdigital");
packages.add("com.sec.android.widgetapp.easyfavoritescontactswidget");
packages.add("com.sec.android.widgetapp.notificationwidget");
packages.add("com.sec.app.RilErrorNotifier");
packages.add("com.sec.bcservice");
packages.add("com.sec.chaton");
packages.add("com.sec.dsm.phone");
packages.add("com.sec.dsm.system");
packages.add("com.sec.esdk.elm");
packages.add("com.sec.factory");
packages.add("com.sec.factory.camera");
packages.add("com.sec.hearingadjust");
packages.add("com.sec.modem.settings");
packages.add("com.sec.phone");
packages.add("com.sec.setdefaultlauncher");
packages.add("com.tripadvisor.tripadvisor");
packages.add("com.vlingo.midas");
packages.add("com.wsomacp");
packages.add("com.wssnps");
packages.add("com.wssyncmldm");
packages.add("org.simalliance.openmobileapi.service");

// Not common packages
packages.add("com.android.apps.tag");
packages.add("com.android.clipboardsaveservice");
packages.add("com.android.pagebuddynotisvc");
packages.add("com.android.pickuptutorial");
packages.add("com.arcsoft.picturesbest.app");
packages.add("com.blurb.checkout");
packages.add("com.coyotesystems.androidSFR");
packages.add("com.dropbox.android");
packages.add("com.ea.nfshift_sfr");
packages.add("com.ea.tetris");
packages.add("com.google.android.apps.docs");
packages.add("com.osp.app.signin");
packages.add("com.policydm");
packages.add("com.popcap.peggle_sfr");
packages.add("com.popcap.pvz");
packages.add("com.qualcomm.gesturesdkoverlayservice");
packages.add("com.samsung.android.app.episodes");
packages.add("com.samsung.android.app.storyalbumwidget");
packages.add("com.samsung.android.app.watchmanagerstub");
packages.add("com.samsung.android.walletmanager");
packages.add("com.samsung.groupcast");
packages.add("com.sec.allsharecastplayer");
packages.add("com.sec.android.app.SamsungContentsAgent");
packages.add("com.sec.android.app.collage");
packages.add("com.sec.android.app.mediasync");
packages.add("com.sec.android.app.minimode.res");
packages.add("com.sec.android.app.twdvfs");
packages.add("com.sec.android.app.wfdbroker");
packages.add("com.sec.android.app.wlantest");
packages.add("com.sec.android.cloudagent.dropboxoobe");
packages.add("com.sec.android.fwupgrade");
packages.add("com.sec.android.mimage.photoretouching");
packages.add("com.sec.android.motions.settings.panningtutorial");
packages.add("com.sec.android.nearby.mediaserver");
packages.add("com.sec.android.widget.samsungapps");
packages.add("com.sec.android.widgetapp.diotek.smemo");
packages.add("com.sec.android.widgetapp.programmonitorwidget");
packages.add("com.sec.everglades");
packages.add("com.sec.everglades.update");
packages.add("com.sec.pcw");
packages.add("com.sfr.android.appliscope");
packages.add("com.sfr.android.console");
packages.add("com.sfr.android.mobiletv");
packages.add("com.sfr.android.moncompte");
packages.add("com.sfr.android.portail");
packages.add("com.sfr.android.sfr_presse");
packages.add("com.sfr.android.sfrcloud");
packages.add("com.sfr.android.sfrjeux");
packages.add("com.sfr.android.sfrmail");
packages.add("com.sfr.android.sfrwifi");
packages.add("com.sfr.android.vvm");
packages.add("flipboard.app");
packages.add("fr.amazon.mShop.android");
packages.add("tv.peel.samsung.app");
packages.add("com.chillingo.spiderjack.row");
packages.add("com.dailymotion.dailymotion");
packages.add("com.dropbox.android");
packages.add("com.epson.mobilephone.samsungprintservice");
packages.add("com.gameloft.android.GloftCITY");
packages.add("com.gameloft.android.GloftFAIM");
packages.add("com.ggb.development");
packages.add("com.hp.android.printservice");
packages.add("com.lookout");
packages.add("com.orange.appshop");
packages.add("com.orange.cos");
packages.add("com.orange.fr.cloudorange");
packages.add("com.orange.nfcwallet.fr");
packages.add("com.orange.orangeetmoi");
packages.add("com.orange.owtv");
packages.add("com.orange.rescue.fr");
packages.add("com.orange.vvm");
packages.add("com.orange.world");
packages.add("com.osp.app.signin");
packages.add("com.samsung.clipboardsaveservice");
packages.add("com.samsung.music");
packages.add("com.samsung.pickuptutorial");
packages.add("com.sec.android.app.launcher");
packages.add("com.sec.android.app.memo");
packages.add("com.sec.android.app.minimode.res");
packages.add("com.sec.android.app.mobileprint");
packages.add("com.sec.android.app.voicerecorder");
packages.add("com.sec.android.app.wlantest");
packages.add("com.sec.android.apps.nfctag");
packages.add("com.sec.android.msc.mediabridge");
packages.add("com.sec.android.pagebuddynotisvc");
packages.add("com.sec.android.widgetapp.activeapplicationwidget");
packages.add("com.sec.android.widgetapp.digitalclock2x1");
packages.add("com.sec.android.widgetapp.memo");
packages.add("com.sec.android.widgetapp.webmanual");
packages.add("com.sec.app.samsungprintservice");
packages.add("com.sec.readershub");
packages.add("com.sec.readershub2.store");
packages.add("com.siso.app.generic");
packages.add("com.siso.app.genericprintservice");
packages.add("com.visionobjects.resourcemanager");
packages.add("deezer.android.app");
packages.add("fr.orange.cineday");
```

My problem is when I reboot the device, it keeps rebooting infinitely. It just goes to the PIN code screen and then reboot after 1 sec.

So far, I've found these lines in the logs:

```
07-31 10:33:18.169: W/LicenseLogService(9197): log() is called by non admin
07-31 10:33:18.179: I/Process(9197): Sending signal. PID: 9197 SIG: 9
07-31 10:33:18.229: I/ServiceManager(264): service 'multiwindow' died
07-31 10:33:18.229: I/ServiceManager(264): service 'batteryinfo' died
07-31 10:33:18.229: I/ServiceManager(264): service 'activity' died
07-31 10:33:18.229: I/ServiceManager(264): service 'account' died
07-31 10:33:18.229: I/ServiceManager(264): service 'content' died
07-31 10:33:18.229: I/ServiceManager(264): service 'mount' died
07-31 10:33:18.229: I/ServiceManager(264): service 'lock_settings' died
07-31 10:33:18.229: I/ServiceManager(264): service 'DirEncryptService' died
07-31 10:33:18.229: I/ServiceManager(264): service 'usagestats' died
07-31 10:33:18.229: I/ServiceManager(264): service 'container_service' died
07-31 10:33:18.229: I/ServiceManager(264): service 'enterprise_vpn_policy' died
07-31 10:33:18.229: I/ServiceManager(264): service 'netpolicy' died
07-31 10:33:18.229: I/ServiceManager(264): service 'statusbar' died
07-31 10:33:18.229: I/ServiceManager(264): service 'enterprise_sso_policy' died
07-31 10:33:18.229: I/ServiceManager(264): service 'enterprise_container_policy' died
07-31 10:33:18.229: I/ServiceManager(264): service 'enterprise_isl_policy' died
07-31 10:33:18.229: I/ServiceManager(264): service 'certificate_policy' died
07-31 10:33:18.229: I/ServiceManager(264): service 'apn_settings_policy' died
07-31 10:33:18.229: I/ServiceManager(264): service 'browser_policy' died
07-31 10:33:18.229: I/ServiceManager(264): service 'date_time_policy' died
07-31 10:33:18.229: I/ServiceManager(264): service 'kioskmode' died
07-31 10:33:18.229: I/ServiceManager(264): service 'apppermission_control_policy' died
07-31 10:33:18.229: I/ServiceManager(264): service 'netstats' died
07-31 10:33:18.229: I/ServiceManager(264): service 'network_management' died
07-31 10:33:18.229: I/ServiceManager(264): service 'textservices' died
07-31 10:33:18.229: I/ServiceManager(264): service 'clipboardEx' died
07-31 10:33:18.229: I/ServiceManager(264): service 'edm_proxy' died
07-31 10:33:18.229: I/ServiceManager(264): service 'ldap_account_policy' died
07-31 10:33:18.229: I/ServiceManager(264): service 'lockscreen_overlay' died
07-31 10:33:18.229: I/ServiceManager(264): service 'geofencing' died
07-31 10:33:18.229: I/ServiceManager(264): service 'clipboard' died
07-31 10:33:18.229: I/ServiceManager(264): service 'device_account_policy' died
```

I may be disabling some required packages but I don't know which ones. I've tried to use a dichotomic algorythm to find out the buggy line but without success.

Should you have any idea on how to fix that ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've managed to do it on my own.
Here is the list of the packages you can disable on Samsung devices

```
// Common packages
packages.add("android.googleSearch.googleSearchWidget");
packages.add("com.LocalFota");
packages.add("com.android.backupconfirm");
packages.add("com.android.bluetooth");
packages.add("com.android.browser.provider");
packages.add("com.android.calendar");
packages.add("com.android.chrome");
packages.add("com.android.dreams.basic");
packages.add("com.android.dreams.phototable");
packages.add("com.android.email");
packages.add("com.android.exchange");
packages.add("com.android.htmlviewer");
packages.add("com.android.mms");
packages.add("com.android.musicfx");
packages.add("com.android.nfc");
packages.add("com.android.noisefield");
packages.add("com.android.phasebeam");
packages.add("com.android.sharedstoragebackup");
packages.add("com.android.stk");
packages.add("com.android.vending");
packages.add("com.android.vpndialogs");
packages.add("com.android.wallpaper.livepicker");
packages.add("com.google.android.apps.books");
packages.add("com.google.android.apps.magazines");
packages.add("com.google.android.apps.plus");
packages.add("com.google.android.apps.uploader");
packages.add("com.google.android.backup");
packages.add("com.google.android.configupdater");
packages.add("com.google.android.feedback");
packages.add("com.google.android.gm");
packages.add("com.google.android.gms");
packages.add("com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox");
packages.add("com.google.android.marvin.talkback");
packages.add("com.google.android.music");
packages.add("com.google.android.partnersetup");
packages.add("com.google.android.play.games");
packages.add("com.google.android.setupwizard");
packages.add("com.google.android.street");
packages.add("com.google.android.syncadapters.calendar");
packages.add("com.google.android.syncadapters.contacts");
packages.add("com.google.android.talk");
packages.add("com.google.android.tts");
packages.add("com.google.android.videos");
packages.add("com.google.android.voicesearch");
packages.add("com.google.android.youtube");
packages.add("com.infraware.polarisviewer5");
packages.add("com.lifevibes.trimapp");
packages.add("com.monotype.android.font.chococooky");
packages.add("com.monotype.android.font.cooljazz");
packages.add("com.monotype.android.font.droidserifitalic");
packages.add("com.monotype.android.font.rosemary");
packages.add("com.monotype.android.font.samsungsans");
packages.add("com.qualcomm.privinit");
packages.add("com.qualcomm.timeservice");
packages.add("com.samsung.android.app.assistantmenu");
packages.add("com.samsung.android.app.colorblind");
packages.add("com.samsung.android.app.shareaccessibilitysettings");
packages.add("com.samsung.android.service.travel");
packages.add("com.samsung.android.tripwidget");
packages.add("com.samsung.android.widgetapp.briefing4x2");
packages.add("com.samsung.app.playreadyui");
packages.add("com.samsung.everglades.video");
packages.add("com.samsung.helphub");
packages.add("com.samsung.klmsagent");
packages.add("com.samsung.scrc.idi.server");
packages.add("com.samsung.shareshot");
packages.add("com.sec.android.Kies");
packages.add("com.sec.android.allshare.service.controlshare");
packages.add("com.sec.android.allshare.service.fileshare");
packages.add("com.sec.android.allshare.service.mediashare");
packages.add("com.sec.android.app.FileShareClient");
packages.add("com.sec.android.app.FileShareServer");
packages.add("com.sec.android.app.SecSetupWizard");
packages.add("com.sec.android.app.bluetoothtest");
packages.add("com.sec.android.app.camera");
packages.add("com.sec.android.app.controlpanel");
packages.add("com.sec.android.app.easylauncher");
packages.add("com.sec.android.app.factorykeystring");
packages.add("com.sec.android.app.fm");
packages.add("com.sec.android.app.hwmoduletest");
packages.add("com.sec.android.app.keyguard");
packages.add("com.sec.android.app.keyguardbackuprestore");
packages.add("com.sec.android.app.kieswifi");
packages.add("com.sec.android.app.launcher");
packages.add("com.sec.android.app.mt");
packages.add("com.sec.android.app.music");
packages.add("com.sec.android.app.myfiles");
packages.add("com.sec.android.app.nfctest");
packages.add("com.sec.android.app.parser");
packages.add("com.sec.android.app.personalization");
packages.add("com.sec.android.app.popupcalculator");
packages.add("com.sec.android.app.popupuireceiver");
packages.add("com.sec.android.app.ringtoneBR");
packages.add("com.sec.android.app.safetyassurance");
packages.add("com.sec.android.app.samsungapps");
packages.add("com.sec.android.app.samsungapps.una2");
packages.add("com.sec.android.app.sbrowser");
packages.add("com.sec.android.app.sbrowsertry");
packages.add("com.sec.android.app.sns3");
packages.add("com.sec.android.app.sysscope");
packages.add("com.sec.android.app.translator");
packages.add("com.sec.android.app.videoplayer");
packages.add("com.sec.android.app.voicerecorder");
packages.add("com.sec.android.app.wallpaperchooser");
packages.add("com.sec.android.cloudagent");
packages.add("com.sec.android.daemonapp");
packages.add("com.sec.android.directconnect");
packages.add("com.sec.android.directshare");
packages.add("com.sec.android.drmpopup");
packages.add("com.sec.android.easysettings");
packages.add("com.sec.android.fotaclient");
packages.add("com.sec.android.gallery3d");
packages.add("com.sec.android.mmapp");
packages.add("com.sec.android.preloadinstaller");
packages.add("com.sec.android.sCloudBackupApp");
packages.add("com.sec.android.sCloudBackupProvider");
packages.add("com.sec.android.sCloudRelayData");
packages.add("com.sec.android.sCloudSync");
packages.add("com.sec.android.sCloudSyncCalendar");
packages.add("com.sec.android.sCloudSyncContacts");
packages.add("com.sec.android.sCloudSyncSBrowserBookMark");
packages.add("com.sec.android.sCloudSyncSBrowserTabs");
packages.add("com.sec.android.sCloudSyncSNote");
packages.add("com.sec.android.saslideshow");
packages.add("com.sec.android.scloud.quota");
packages.add("com.sec.android.service.health.sensor");
packages.add("com.sec.android.widgetapp.SPlannerAppWidget");
packages.add("com.sec.android.widgetapp.alarmwidget");
packages.add("com.sec.android.widgetapp.ap.hero.accuweather");
packages.add("com.sec.android.widgetapp.ap.yahoonews");
packages.add("com.sec.android.widgetapp.ap.yahoostock.stockclock");
packages.add("com.sec.android.widgetapp.digitalclock");
packages.add("com.sec.android.widgetapp.dualclockdigital");
packages.add("com.sec.android.widgetapp.easyfavoritescontactswidget");
packages.add("com.sec.android.widgetapp.notificationwidget");
packages.add("com.sec.app.RilErrorNotifier");
packages.add("com.sec.chaton");
packages.add("com.sec.esdk.elm");
packages.add("com.sec.factory");
packages.add("com.sec.factory.camera");
packages.add("com.sec.hearingadjust");
packages.add("com.sec.setdefaultlauncher");
packages.add("com.tripadvisor.tripadvisor");
packages.add("com.vlingo.midas");
packages.add("com.wsomacp");
packages.add("com.wssnps");
packages.add("com.wssyncmldm");
packages.add("org.simalliance.openmobileapi.service");

// Not common packages
packages.add("com.android.apps.tag");
packages.add("com.android.clipboardsaveservice");
packages.add("com.android.pagebuddynotisvc");
packages.add("com.android.pickuptutorial");
packages.add("com.arcsoft.picturesbest.app");
packages.add("com.blurb.checkout");
packages.add("com.coyotesystems.androidSFR");
packages.add("com.dropbox.android");
packages.add("com.ea.nfshift_sfr");
packages.add("com.ea.tetris");
packages.add("com.google.android.apps.docs");
packages.add("com.osp.app.signin");
packages.add("com.policydm");
packages.add("com.popcap.peggle_sfr");
packages.add("com.popcap.pvz");
packages.add("com.qualcomm.gesturesdkoverlayservice");
packages.add("com.samsung.android.app.episodes");
packages.add("com.samsung.android.app.storyalbumwidget");
packages.add("com.samsung.android.app.watchmanagerstub");
packages.add("com.samsung.android.walletmanager");
packages.add("com.samsung.groupcast");
packages.add("com.sec.allsharecastplayer");
packages.add("com.sec.android.app.SamsungContentsAgent");
packages.add("com.sec.android.app.collage");
packages.add("com.sec.android.app.mediasync");
packages.add("com.sec.android.app.minimode.res");
packages.add("com.sec.android.app.twdvfs");
packages.add("com.sec.android.app.wfdbroker");
packages.add("com.sec.android.app.wlantest");
packages.add("com.sec.android.cloudagent.dropboxoobe");
packages.add("com.sec.android.fwupgrade");
packages.add("com.sec.android.mimage.photoretouching");
packages.add("com.sec.android.motions.settings.panningtutorial");
packages.add("com.sec.android.nearby.mediaserver");
packages.add("com.sec.android.widget.samsungapps");
packages.add("com.sec.android.widgetapp.diotek.smemo");
packages.add("com.sec.android.widgetapp.programmonitorwidget");
packages.add("com.sec.everglades");
packages.add("com.sec.everglades.update");
packages.add("com.sec.pcw");
packages.add("com.sfr.android.appliscope");
packages.add("com.sfr.android.console");
packages.add("com.sfr.android.mobiletv");
packages.add("com.sfr.android.moncompte");
packages.add("com.sfr.android.portail");
packages.add("com.sfr.android.sfr_presse");
packages.add("com.sfr.android.sfrcloud");
packages.add("com.sfr.android.sfrjeux");
packages.add("com.sfr.android.sfrmail");
packages.add("com.sfr.android.sfrwifi");
packages.add("com.sfr.android.vvm");
packages.add("flipboard.app");
packages.add("fr.amazon.mShop.android");
packages.add("tv.peel.samsung.app");
packages.add("com.chillingo.spiderjack.row");
packages.add("com.dailymotion.dailymotion");
packages.add("com.dropbox.android");
packages.add("com.epson.mobilephone.samsungprintservice");
packages.add("com.gameloft.android.GloftCITY");
packages.add("com.gameloft.android.GloftFAIM");
packages.add("com.ggb.development");
packages.add("com.hp.android.printservice");
packages.add("com.lookout");
packages.add("com.orange.appshop");
packages.add("com.orange.cos");
packages.add("com.orange.fr.cloudorange");
packages.add("com.orange.nfcwallet.fr");
packages.add("com.orange.orangeetmoi");
packages.add("com.orange.owtv");
packages.add("com.orange.rescue.fr");
packages.add("com.orange.vvm");
packages.add("com.orange.world");
packages.add("com.osp.app.signin");
packages.add("com.samsung.clipboardsaveservice");
packages.add("com.samsung.music");
packages.add("com.samsung.pickuptutorial");
packages.add("com.sec.android.app.launcher");
packages.add("com.sec.android.app.memo");
packages.add("com.sec.android.app.minimode.res");
packages.add("com.sec.android.app.mobileprint");
packages.add("com.sec.android.app.voicerecorder");
packages.add("com.sec.android.app.wlantest");
packages.add("com.sec.android.apps.nfctag");
packages.add("com.sec.android.msc.mediabridge");
packages.add("com.sec.android.pagebuddynotisvc");
packages.add("com.sec.android.widgetapp.activeapplicationwidget");
packages.add("com.sec.android.widgetapp.digitalclock2x1");
packages.add("com.sec.android.widgetapp.memo");
packages.add("com.sec.android.widgetapp.webmanual");
packages.add("com.sec.app.samsungprintservice");
packages.add("com.sec.readershub");
packages.add("com.sec.readershub2.store");
packages.add("com.siso.app.generic");
packages.add("com.siso.app.genericprintservice");
packages.add("com.visionobjects.resourcemanager");
packages.add("deezer.android.app");
packages.add("fr.orange.cineday");
```

Comment: By far the best list I've come across.  WHat was the one that was causing the bootloop?